# pros and cons of using factory vs regular constructor

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, class-factory

(Using Python 3.2, though I doubt it matters.)

I have `class Data`, `class Rules`, and class `Result`. I use lowercase to denote an instance of the class.

A `rules` object contains rules that, if applied to a `data` object, can create a `result` object.

I'm deciding where to put the (rather complicated and evolving) code that actually applies the rules to the data. I can see two choices:

1. Put that code inside a class `Result` method, say `parse_rules`. `Result` constructor would take as an argument a `rules` object, and pass it onto `self.parse_rules`.
2. Put that code inside a new class `ResultFactory`. `ResultFactory` would be a singleton class, which has a method, say `build_result`, which takes `rules` as an argument and returns a newly built `result` object.

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GRASP design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29) provide guidelines for assigning responsibility to classes and objects in object-oriented design. For example, the *Creator* pattern suggests: In general, a class B should be responsible for creating instances of class A if one, or preferably more, of the following apply:

- Instances of B contains or compositely aggregates instances of A
- Instances of B record instances of A
- Instances of B closely use instances of A
- Instances of B have the initializing information for instances of A and pass it on creation.

In your example, you have complicated and evolving code for applying rules to data.  That suggests the use of the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).

Putting the code in *Results* is contraindicated because 1) results don't *create* results, and 2) results aren't the *information expert* (i.e. they don't have most of the knowledge that is needed).

In short, the *ResultFactory* seems like a reasonable place to concentrate the knowledge of how to apply *rules* to *data* to generate *results*.  If you were to try to push all of this logic into class constructors for either Results or Rules, it would lead to tight coupling and loss of cohesion.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm now going through Craig Larman's book it referenced. Maybe I misunderstood something, but it seems to me that the Creator pattern takes for granted that class A instances are created in A's constructor, and only discusses which class should call that constructor?

Answer (score 2):

#### Third scenario:

You may want to consider a third scenario:

- Put the code inside the method `Rules.__call__`.
  Instantiating `Result` like: `result = rules(data)`

**Pros:**

- `Result`s can be totally unaware of the `Rules` that generates them (and maybe even of the original `Data`).
- Every `Rules` sub-class can customize its `Result` creation.
- It feels natural (to me): `Rules` applied to `Data` yield `Result`.
- And you'll have a couple of GRASP principle on your side:

  - **Creator**: Instances of `Rules` have the initializing information for instances of `Result` and pass it on creation.
  - **Information Expert**: Information Expert will lead to placing the responsibility on the class with the most information required to fulfill it.

**Side effects:**

- **Coupling**: You'll raise the coupling between `Rules` and `Data`:

  - You need to pass the *whole* data set to every `Rules`
  - Which means that each `Rules` should be able to decide on which data it'll be applied.

Comment: Please, let me know what you think, and if can fit your problem.

Comment: I am still not sure what works; I'll update when I get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the rules in their own classes? If you create a RuleBase class, then each rule can derive from it. This way, polymorphism can be used when Data needs rules applied. Data doesn't need to know or care which Rule instances were applied (unless Data itself is the one who knows which rules should be applied).

When rules need to be invoked, a data instance can all RuleBase.ExecuteRules() and pass itself in as an argument. The correct subclass of Rule can be chosen directly from Data, if Data knows which Rule is necessary. Or some other design pattern can be used, like Chain of Responsibility, where Data invokes the pattern and lets a Result come back.

This would make a great whiteboard discussion.

Comment: Rules do reside in their own classes; I didn't mention it, but `Rules` is a root of a large class hierarchy. So if I want to put the transformation code into Rules, I certainly can put it in the root of this hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make ResultFactory a pure function? It's not useful to create a singleton object if all you need is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second is downright silly, especially with all the singletonness. If `Result` requires `Rules` to create an instance, and you can't create one without it, it should take that as an argument to `__init__`. No pattern shopping necessary.

Comment: So what would have to change in my scenario, for a class factory to actually make sense?

Comment: @max: I don't know. Apply common sense, see which approach is simpler. I guess turning `Rules` into a factory might be an option, if you can create `Result` instances separately, by passing all the data through constructor. But if you always need `Rules` to create `Result`, then it should be a ctor argument.